# Realm DB in Swift And Object Mapper (Json)

Tags: json, swift, realm

Halo Guys, i'm new on Swift Programming, i had a problem, i use a Realm DB to storing my data's after user has been authenticated. the result that came from server apps has been mapped to be json string, its work, and after json converted to be object / model, i put it into the realm DB,

below is the code's :

```
print(response.text)
                let requestResult:RequestResult = Mapper<RequestResult>().map(response.text)!
                var publicLogin : PublicLogin = Mapper<PublicLogin>().map(requestResult.result)!
                let t : String = Mapper<PublicLogin>().toJSONString(publicLogin)!
                print("TTT===== "+t)
                dispatch_sync(dispatch_queue_create("background", nil)){
                    let realm = try! Realm()
                    try! realm.write{
                        realm.add(publicLogin)
                        publicLogin = realm.objects(PublicLogin.self)[0]
                        let x : String = Mapper<PublicLogin>().toJSONString(publicLogin)!
                        print(" ########## \n : "+x)
                        let sideMenu = SSASideMenu(contentViewController: UINavigationController(rootViewController: HomeViewController()), leftMenuViewController: LeftMenuViewController(), rightMenuViewController: RightMenuViewController())
                        let color:UIColor = UIColor(netHex:0x000000)
                        sideMenu.view.backgroundColor = color
                        sideMenu.configure(SSASideMenu.MenuViewEffect(fade: true, scale: true, scaleBackground: false))
                        sideMenu.configure(SSASideMenu.ContentViewEffect(alpha: 1.0, scale: 0.7))
                        sideMenu.configure(SSASideMenu.ContentViewShadow(enabled: true, color: UIColor.blackColor(), opacity: 0.6, radius: 6.0))
                        self.presentViewController(sideMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        self.loginButton.selected = false ;
                        progress.Close()
                    }
                }
```

i was make sure, the json data firsttime has been valid, i place the console / log below to detailing my case :

[image]

But after i put into realm DB and try to get back, it seems null / nil objects, below is console / log

[image]

The **{}** string should be a json object... this is the problem

Can anybody help me to explain the right way using realm DB or if you notice the mistake in my code's ? Thanks.

Comment: 1. You should add the way you are trying to read from DB. 2. Are you setting object with unique identifier? 3. You are making UI actions, on back thread. This is not good practice.

Comment: 1 - Yes sir, i did that way. i notice its simply like example: realm.objects(PublicLogin.self)[0]
2 - Not yet Sir, i will add later, i read from documentation, its use for update functionality, so i thought it's only needed if i want to update existing data in realm db
3 - i made synchronous because the UI should be appear if only if the resut has came from server and put into the realm db, if not its should be not changing the page / UI

Comment: 2. So how are you trying to access that object? you are missing code.. 3. You should never change UI on back thread. If you are waiting for an async task to finish, you can still move back to UI thread and change it. It will effect you in very strange ways, or just not work.

Comment: 2 - you can look at the code's above Sir, thats way i used to access the object, please give me example..
3 - No,, i mean i have to waiting the task and keep from any change in my UI, the user should be waiting and do not anything before task finished.. its like simply authentication, where the UI state is have to be keep on progress without any action in another / UI thread

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly where the force unwrap is happening that's causing this fatal error. Assuming it's the `toJSONString(publicLogin)!` line, this is where I'd recommend using Xcode and LLDB to step through the function and identify why it's returning `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to save the object and then access it at the same write transaction. You should save it in a write transaction, and then access it after the transaction block is finished.
Beside that, you are changing UI elements, at a back thread, and inside a write transaction, this is wrong. Like I sad, dealing with UI only on main thread.

Here is an example:

```
let requestResult:RequestResult = Mapper<RequestResult>().map(response.text)!
var publicLogin : PublicLogin = Mapper<PublicLogin>().map(requestResult.result)!
let t : String = Mapper<PublicLogin>().toJSONString(publicLogin)!
print("TTT===== "+t)
dispatch_sync(dispatch_queue_create("background", nil)){
    let realm = try! Realm()
    try! realm.write{
        realm.add(publicLogin)
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { 
        publicLogin = realm.objects(PublicLogin.self)[0]
        let x : String = Mapper<PublicLogin>().toJSONString(publicLogin)!
        print(" ########## \n : "+x)
        let sideMenu = SSASideMenu(contentViewController: UINavigationController(rootViewController: HomeViewController()), leftMenuViewController: LeftMenuViewController(), rightMenuViewController: RightMenuViewController())
        let color:UIColor = UIColor(netHex:0x000000)
        sideMenu.view.backgroundColor = color
        sideMenu.configure(SSASideMenu.MenuViewEffect(fade: true, scale: true, scaleBackground: false))
        sideMenu.configure(SSASideMenu.ContentViewEffect(alpha: 1.0, scale: 0.7))
        sideMenu.configure(SSASideMenu.ContentViewShadow(enabled: true, color: UIColor.blackColor(), opacity: 0.6, radius: 6.0))
        self.presentViewController(sideMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.loginButton.selected = false ;
        progress.Close()
    })
}
```

I would recommend you to not even move to back thread for this update, write transaction isn't a very heavy compered to the contexet switch between threads you are doing here.. again it depends on the on the circumstances..
You can just keep it simple like this:

```
   let requestResult:RequestResult = Mapper<RequestResult>().map(response.text)!
    var publicLogin : PublicLogin = Mapper<PublicLogin>().map(requestResult.result)!
    let t : String = Mapper<PublicLogin>().toJSONString(publicLogin)!
    print("TTT===== "+t)
        let realm = try! Realm()
        try! realm.write{
            realm.add(publicLogin)
        }
    publicLogin = realm.objects(PublicLogin.self)[0]
    let x : String = Mapper<PublicLogin>().toJSONString(publicLogin)!
    print(" ########## \n : "+x)
    let sideMenu = SSASideMenu(contentViewController: UINavigationController(rootViewController: HomeViewController()), leftMenuViewController: LeftMenuViewController(), rightMenuViewController: RightMenuViewController())
    let color:UIColor = UIColor(netHex:0x000000)
    sideMenu.view.backgroundColor = color
    sideMenu.configure(SSASideMenu.MenuViewEffect(fade: true, scale: true, scaleBackground: false))
    sideMenu.configure(SSASideMenu.ContentViewEffect(alpha: 1.0, scale: 0.7))
    sideMenu.configure(SSASideMenu.ContentViewShadow(enabled: true, color: UIColor.blackColor(), opacity: 0.6, radius: 6.0))
    self.presentViewController(sideMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
    self.loginButton.selected = false ;
    progress.Close()
```